# How to add a graphQL field to a sublevel item in Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql

I have a piece of code to add endpoints/fields to graphQL and I can successfully add to the root or items that are in root. I am however unable to add to a deeper nested item.

```
register_graphql_field('cart', 'cartProductName', [
'type' => 'String',
'description' => "Get product name for cart",
'resolve' => function ($data) {
    global $wpdb;
    $return = "Banana!";
    return $return;
}
]);
```

This will add "cartProductName" to Root -> cart.. I need to add it to Root -> cart -> content -> nodes -> product -> node

[Screenshot of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyoqn.png)

Comment: node has syme type (check playground docs) - extend this type

Comment: Not really following, I started to code against graphQL yesterday so I'm extremely green when it comes to this :)

Firstly. Where do I find the playground docs? Google suggest a lot of different sources and it's hard to tell which is what..

Secondly, assuming you mean "same type".. same type as what? extend?

Comment: "some type" .... playground = graphiql => https://www.wpgraphql.com/docs/interacting-with-wpgraphql/ - docs on the right